# Cronjob for automatic process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, cron

I need to set a cronjob for every month, since i'm new to scripting i'm confused with the script.

For example i need to set cronjob for -5 and +2 working days of every month end.

For November 11/24/2014 , 25,26,27,28, to December 11/1/2014, 02 days.

How to script cronjob for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will test if today is one of the last 5 or first 2 working days of the month.  If so, it will executed `/path/command`.  For this code, it is assumed that workdays are Monday through Friday.  This script should be run once a day:

```
#!/bin/bash
do_run() {
    dom=$(date '+%_d') # 1-31, day of month
    dow=$(date '+%u') # 1-7 with 1=Monday, day of week
    currentm=$(date '+%_m')
    nextm=$(date -d '+7 days' '+%_m')
    limit=(0 4 4 2 2 2)
    [ "$dow" -le 5 ] && {
        [ "$dom" -le "${limit[$dow]}" ] ||
        [ "$currentm" -ne "$nextm" ]
    }
}

do_run && /path/command
```

#### How it works:

`do_run` returns true if today is (1) a workday and either (2) it is one of the first two workdays of the month, or (3) is one of the last five workdays of the month.  Taking it one piece at a time:

- `do_run()`

  This starts the definition of a shell function called `do_run`.
- `dom=$(date '+%_d')`

  This sets the shell variable `dom` to the day of the month.  This will be a number from 1 to 31.
- `dow=$(date '+%u')`

  This sets the shell variable `dow` to the day of the week with 1=Monday and 7=Sunday.
- `currentm=$(date '+%_m')`

  This sets the shell variable `currentm` to number of the month with 1=January and 12=December.
- `nextm=$(date -d '+7 days' '+%_m')`

  This sets the shell variable `nextm` to the number of the month that it would be 7 days from now.
- `limit=(0 4 4 2 2 2)`

  This defines the shell array `limit`. (see below.)
- `[ "$dow" -le 5 ]`

  This returns true if the current day is a weekday
- `[ "$dom" -le "${limit[$dow]}" ]`

  This returns true if the day-of-the-month is less than or equal to the limit for this day-of-the-week.

  As an example, consider a month in which the fourth is a Monday.  For this case, `dom=4` and `dow=1`.  From the definition of `limit`, `${limit[$dow]}` is 4.  Since 4 is less than or equal to 4, this test returns true, correctly indicating that this Monday is one of the first two workdays of the month.
- `[ "$currentm" -ne "$nextm" ]`

  This returns true if we are within the last week of the month.

  The above three tests are combined logically with `&&` and `||` to return true if today is one of the first 2 or last 5 workdays of the month.
- `do_run && /path/command`

  If `do_run` returns true, then `/path/command` will be executed.  Otherwise, it will not be executed.

Comment: If suppose i have to set the cron job 1st working day of the month, then how will set the cron job for this??? @John1024

Comment: I have a doubt in this script, dow=$(date '+%u'). In this the value of sunday=0 or 7; I'm confused with this? Because in crontab we will define 0= sunday and goes on..... Please clarify this... @Joh1024

Comment: @Shirchabayshan __(A)__ The simplest is to have `cron` run this script _every_ day. This script will run `/path/command` only on the days you want. __(B)__ `date '+%u'` returns 1 to 7 with 1=Monday and 7=Sunday. Thus `[ "$dow" -le 5 ]` is true on weekdays and only on weekdays. This is documented in `man date`.  Yes, the crontab convention is different but that doesn't matter here where we are using `date` and `test` (`[`).

Answer (score 2):

No need for scripting, just set it in "crontab"

```
crontab -e


* * 24-31 * 1-5    /path/command
* * 1-2   * 1-5    /path/command
```

"crontab" can handle ranges and comma separated lists. Please see "man 5 crontab" or this rather good guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Depending on where you are located working days may be different. Western working week assumed here i.e. "1-5" = monday-friday.

Please check that 24. day --- 2. day covers the cases when weekend is at different place.
I also suggest to run

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

before starting "crontab -e" unless you are familiar with "vim" editor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but every month the working days will change, for that how do i go? @ajaaskel

Comment: You don't work Monday through Friday some weeks?  Or what do you mean?

Comment: Right now my working days are Mo-Fr but I have been previously working in another country first Sa-We, later Su-Th. Weekend is different in Middle East.

Comment: Ajaaskel, that is a nice, clever solution for the end of the month.  There will be some months, however, for which one or both of the first two work days of the month will be skipped.  Assuming a Mon-Fri work week, March 2014 is an example of a month for which the crontab above would not execute either of the first two work days of the month.  Is that acceptable to you, @Sinsha?

Comment: No, @John1024, Please could you assist any solution for this?